# How to insert numerous rows on a table from another table with conditions on Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I do have a problem on how to insert numerous rows of data into a table from an existing table with conditions. So this first code is how I created my table.

```
CREATE TABLE MARKETING_COMMODITY
AS(
SELECT A.DTIME_SIGNATURE 
, A.AMT_SIGNED  
, A.CNT_SIGNED
, A.APPLICATION_AMOUNT
, A.PRODUCT 
, A.PRODUCT_TYPE 
, A.PRODUCT_PRICE 
, VSR.NAME_PRODUCER
, vsr.text_model_number
, vsp.partner_name 
, vsp.partner_brand 
, vspl.salesroom 
, vspl.mall 

FROM DM_SALES.V_SALES_DM_DATA A 

  LEFT JOIN DM_SALES.V_SALES_DM_PARTNER VSP ON A.CODE_SALESROOM_PARTNER = VSP.CODE_SALESROOM_PARTNER 
  LEFT JOIN dm_sales.v_sales_dm_pos_list vspl on a.code_salesroom = vspl.code_salesroom 
  LEFT JOIN DM_SALES.V_SALES_DM_CONTRACT_BUNDLE VSR ON A.CONTRACT_NUMBER = VSR.CONTRACT_NUMBER 

WHERE 1=1
  AND a.contract_state <> 'Cancelled' 
  AND a.cnt_signed=1 
  AND A.LOAN_TYPE = 'Consumer Loan'
AND (TRUNC(A.DTIME_SIGNATURE) BETWEEN DATE'2022-01-01' AND DATE'2022-08-31') 
;
```

And this is how I'd like to insert my new rows (*its like updating the table to get the new data up to the current day*)

```
INSERT INTO MARKETING_COMMODITY
VALUES(
SELECT A.DTIME_SIGNATURE 
, A.AMT_SIGNED  
, A.CNT_SIGNED
, A.APPLICATION_AMOUNT
, A.PRODUCT 
, A.PRODUCT_TYPE 
, A.PRODUCT_PRICE 
, VSR.NAME_PRODUCER
, vsr.text_model_number
, vsp.partner_name 
, vsp.partner_brand 
, vspl.salesroom 
, vspl.mall 

FROM DM_SALES.V_SALES_DM_DATA A 

  LEFT JOIN DM_SALES.V_SALES_DM_PARTNER VSP ON A.CODE_SALESROOM_PARTNER = VSP.CODE_SALESROOM_PARTNER 
  LEFT JOIN dm_sales.v_sales_dm_pos_list vspl on a.code_salesroom = vspl.code_salesroom 
  LEFT JOIN DM_SALES.V_SALES_DM_CONTRACT_BUNDLE VSR ON A.CONTRACT_NUMBER = VSR.CONTRACT_NUMBER 

WHERE 1=1
  AND a.contract_state <> 'Cancelled' 
  AND a.cnt_signed=1 
  AND A.LOAN_TYPE = 'Consumer Loan'
AND (TRUNC(A.DTIME_SIGNATURE) BETWEEN DATE'2022-09-01' AND DATE'2022-09-10') 
;
```

What can you suggest? Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem with your current approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't confuse the syntax for "*CREATE TABLE AS SELECT*" with the syntax for "*INSERT INTO SELECT*". Explicitely add the columns you're inserting into and remove the "AS" keyword. This should work:

```
INSERT INTO MARKETING_COMMODITY
(
 dtime_signature 
,amt_signed  
,cnt_signed
,application_amount
,product 
,product_type 
,product_price 
,name_producer
,text_model_number
,partner_name 
,partner_brand 
,salesroom 
,mall 
)
SELECT A.DTIME_SIGNATURE 
, A.AMT_SIGNED  
, A.CNT_SIGNED
, A.APPLICATION_AMOUNT
, A.PRODUCT 
, A.PRODUCT_TYPE 
, A.PRODUCT_PRICE 
, VSR.NAME_PRODUCER
, vsr.text_model_number
, vsp.partner_name 
, vsp.partner_brand 
, vspl.salesroom 
, vspl.mall 

FROM DM_SALES.V_SALES_DM_DATA A 

  LEFT JOIN DM_SALES.V_SALES_DM_PARTNER VSP ON A.CODE_SALESROOM_PARTNER = VSP.CODE_SALESROOM_PARTNER 
  LEFT JOIN dm_sales.v_sales_dm_pos_list vspl on a.code_salesroom = vspl.code_salesroom 
  LEFT JOIN DM_SALES.V_SALES_DM_CONTRACT_BUNDLE VSR ON A.CONTRACT_NUMBER = VSR.CONTRACT_NUMBER 

WHERE 1=1
  AND a.contract_state <> 'Cancelled' 
  AND a.cnt_signed=1 
  AND A.LOAN_TYPE = 'Consumer Loan'
AND (TRUNC(A.DTIME_SIGNATURE) BETWEEN DATE'2022-09-01' AND DATE'2022-09-10') 
;
```